# Selecting from Same Column into different variables

Tags: select, plsql, where-clause, oracle12c, select-into

```
 Values                 Id's
    
    1                   120
    1                   120
    0                   120
    0                   120
    0                   120
    Not applicable      120
    Not applicable      120
    Empty               120
```

I wanted to select the count of values 1 into different variable and count of 0 into different variable with the single select statement. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible? Sure, here's one option. Sample data in lines #1 - 10; query you might use begins at line #11.

```
SQL> with test (value, id) as
  2    (select 'n/a'  , 120 from dual union all
  3     select 'n/a'  , 120 from dual union all
  4     select 'empty', 120 from dual union all
  5     select '1'    , 120 from dual union all
  6     select '1'    , 120 from dual union all
  7     select '0'    , 120 from dual union all
  8     select '0'    , 120 from dual union all
  9     select '0'    , 120 from dual
 10    )
 11  select sum(case when value = '1' then 1 else 0 end) cnt_1,
 12         sum(case when value = '0' then 1 else 0 end) cnt_0
 13  from test;

     CNT_1      CNT_0
---------- ----------
         2          3

SQL>
```